# Concurrent basicGet from a single RabbitMQ queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

We run multiple concurrent RabbitMQ consumers each one executes “basicGet” in a loop. We see that a single consumer gets most of the messages. Is there a way to spread messages more evenly between all consumers? Basically can we somehow interrupt RabbitMQ serveing the first consumer and switch to the next in line. Note: we must pull messages (basicGet) and cannot switch to push (basicConsume)  Thanks.

Comment: `cannot switch to push (basicConsume)` one of the saddest things I've read today :)

Answer (score 0):

set a consumer prefetch limit of 1, and put the consumer into noAck: false mode.

... that may be autoAck: false, instead of noAck...

this will force your consumer to only retrieve 1 message at a time, and require you to manually ack the message.

with these two things in place, your messages should distribute across multiple consumers more evenly - assuming you have multiple messages in the queue

Comment: Thanks. it's exactly the direction (RabbitMQ interface config) I was looking for. Just I don't think prefetch is relevant to basicGet - it's a basicCOnsume thing. Now I need to try "manual" ack for basicGet to see if it helps. Thank you again.

Comment: i think you're right about prefetch, since basicGet would only grab one message at a time, anyways. :)